# Serial COM port timeout setting

Tags: c#, c++, windows, serial-port

I have a USB to serial COM port that when I run the command in the screenshot below, I see the timeout value is ON.  Where is this setting come from? I can't find anywhere for it when looking at the device properties in my device manager.  Basically I am doing some testing and I would like to turn this value from ON to OFF.

I have some virtual com ports as well and on them the value is OFF.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in the command prompt itself.

```
mode com7 to=off
```

Here, 'to' stands for time-out.
You can check additional commands by using following.

```
mode /?
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, i was doing mode -help hehe..however I tried it on two machine, one works while the other did not...